# Options for when a text has not been translated into English from Spanish

Tags: translation, spanish-language

Several of [Arturo Perez-Reverte's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arturo_P%C3%A9rez-Reverte) works have been translated into English, but in the case of "El Cid" (Sidi), no English version has been published to my knowledge.

I fear my prospects are grim. Auto-translating an e-version would surely cheapen the experience. And I won't be learning Spanish anytime soon. But as a keen reader, I would like to advance the cause of a translation of El Cid, but I don't suppose the publisher will care that much, seeing as I'm just one reader.

### Question

In these types of situations, what options do we as readers have to bridge the gaps between works in originally written in Spanish? Processes of an author/collaborators translating other texts might be helpful too: time frames, trigger, ect.

Comment: Arturo Perez-Reverte's *The Siege* took three years to translate into English, and *What We Become* took four and a half years. I wouldn't give up quite yet.

Comment: @PeterShor Great! That is a point of reference I hadn't thought of, edited question to allow an answer along those lines.

Comment: What do you mean by the last sentence of your question?

Comment: @Spagirl Was thinking if nothing else, seeing how long it took for similar texts to be translated could be a kind of benchmark. By triggers I just meant what tends to the the deciding criterion for texts that end up being translated: trends, readership, author's discretion, ect.